# Incremento de uso de memoria de mi programa en JAVA SE

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, manejo-de-memoria

He creado un programa sencillo en JAVA SE con NETBEANS donde tengo 3 botones y cada vez que pulso un botón me envia una información a mi base de datos, en todo momento tengo la conexión abierta y cada vez que pulso el botón

```
//Creo la conexión

static Connection connection = null;
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connection =DriverManager.getConnection( "jdbc:mysql://midominio.org:3306/nombreDB", "usuario", "contraseña");

//Dejo la conexión abierta y cada vez que pulso un botón realizado este método.
private void insertarRegistro(int id_persona, int tipo_acceso){
            PreparedStatement pst = null;
        try {                
                String sentencia = "INSERT INTO tabla(id_persona, fecha, hora, tipo_acceso) VALUES (?, CURDATE(), CURTIME(), ?)";

                pst = connection .prepareStatement(sentencia);                
                pst.setInt(1, id_persona);
                pst.setInt(2, tipo_acceso);

                pst.executeUpdate();
                pst.close();
            } catch (SQLException ex) {                
                System.out.println("No se ha podido insertar  en la Base de Datos.");                
            } finally{
                    try {
                        pst.close();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {                    
                    }
            }
    }
```

Entoces abro el Administrador de tareas y veo que mi programa en la columna de Memoria cada vez que pulso se va incrementando la memoria pero nunca baja, y llega un momento que consume tanta memoria que se queda enganchado el programa.

¿Como puedo solucionar que no suba la memoria o que cuando se deje de pulsar el botón la memoria vuelva a mas o menos a su valor principal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Respondiendo a tu pregunta:

1. No hay nada en el código que muestras que indique un "memory leak", normalmente un problema de excesivo uso de memoria viene por llamadas recursivas o porque los objetos que se instancian se guardan (por ejemplo, en Maps o Lists) de forma que no se pueden liberar. El driver mysql es tan usado que no creo que sea la causa.

   Un punto que no me queda claro es dónde se crea la conexión. ¿Estás seguro de que sólo estás creando una conexión durante toda la ejecución del programa?

El resto de puntos no responden a la pregunta, son más bien consejos sobre el código:

2. Una de las ventajas de los `PreparedStatement` es que, aunque son lentos para montarse, si se reutilizan cambiando los parámetros son bastante rápidos. Dado que dejas abierta la conexión (cuidado, puede darte errores de timeout si dejas de utilizarla un rato!) ¿por qué no dejar también abierto el `PreparedStatement`? En todo caso, es sólo una cuestión de rendimiento.
3. Si no hay error, con tu código se ejecuta `pst.close()` dos veces. No debería ser grave, pero bueno...
4. Si hay un error antes o durante de la línea `pst = connection .prepareStatement(sentencia)`, el código en el `finally` lanzará un `NullPointerException` porque no se ha asignado ningún valor a `pst`.
5. Si usas Java 7 o superior, puedes usar el `try-with-resources` con el `PreparedStatement`, y librarte de todo el código de cerrarlo (y de los dos puntos de más arriba):

   ```
   try (PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("....")) {
      ...
      // NO pst.close()
   } catch (SQLException sqle) {
     ...
   }
   ```
6. Con drivers JDBC 4.0, ya no debería ser necesario el hacer el `Class.forName()`. De [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html#drivermanager):

   > In previous versions of JDBC, to obtain a connection, you first had to initialize your JDBC driver by calling the method Class.forName. [...]
   >
   > Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are automatically loaded. (However, you must manually load any drivers prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)

Comment: No conocía la opción del Preparedstatement, la aplicaré a partir de ahora, Sobre lo de Memory Leak me puedes recomendar alguna documentación para poder comprobarlo en mi programa? Muchas gracias.

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con "documentación para poder comprobarlo"? En tu método sólo creas un objeto, el `PreparedStatement`; lo cierras correctamente y no guardas ninguna referencia a él, por lo que el garbage collector debería eliminarlo sin ningún problema. Para hacer comprobaciones sobre la ejecución del programa hay herramientas llamadas "profilers", pero puede ser complicado leer la información que proporcionan: https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2014/06/java-performance-tuning-tools/

Comment: Me refería a lo que me has pasado, voy a ver si lo se utilizar, una duda, Con la clase Statement también se puede hace rlos mismo que con el PreparedStatement? Es que tengo otro métdo que lo uso, así tampoco tengo que cerrarlo y siempre ejecuta la misma sentencia. Muchas gracias

Comment: La diferencia entre `Statement` y `PreparedStatement` es que con `Statement` se le pasa el SQL final; no hay sustitución de parámetros (los ?). `Statement` es menos reusable, y no "sanitiza" los parámetros que le pasa (busca `SQL injection` para saber a qué me refiero), pero es más rápido.

Comment: Ok gracias, usaré PreparedStatement para todo

Comment: Reforzando el comentario de que uses sentencias preparadas para todo, te recomiendo veas http://bobbytables.com . Por otro lado, Netbeans tiene su propio profiler: https://profiler.netbeans.org/

Comment: @SJuan76 El ⑥ no es del todo correcto, sobretodo en contenedores de *servlets*. El mecanismo, por defecto, se ejecuta al cargar la clase `DriverManager`, buscando *drivers* a través de un bloque `static`. Y, dependiendo de los cargadores de clases y su jerarquía... si el `DriverManager` ya cargó los *drivers*, ¿qué pasa con los WARs que se despliegan tiempo después? El *driver* ahora se tiene que cargar explícitamente.